# accidentaly turning a card face up during the deal

Tags: texas-hold-em

In poker what if the first card to the last player is turned face up accidently, when does he get a replacement card? Can he be dealt back to back cards?

Answer (score 0):

The technical term for accidentally revealed cards are "exposed" cards.

Generally, misdeals are declared if any of the cards for SB (small blind) and BB (big blind) are exposed. All cards go back into the deck to be reshuffled followed by the deal starting over and the dealing would not continue.

Any other exposed cards (regardless if they're to the third player or to the last, as long as they are in the blinds) are typically to be replaced immediately -- the exposed card is not considered part of the deal, will not go back to the deck, and will instead be used as the burn card. It is to be shown to all players clearly until it becomes the burn card(s). All players will have information of one fewer card in the deck in play.

The other card that didn't get exposed would typically be kept, although house rules to redeal on a non-blinds misdeal may be invoked if too many exposed cards are in play.

However, while it does not align with typical Poker rules, it is pretty common for misdeals to happen especially when the players are doing the dealing themselves, and as such misdeals may be played out regardless just to save time.

Answer (score 0):

This is "house rule" kind of thing that varies from one casino to the next, but generally an exposed card in last (button) position is not a misdeal--the player is simply given the next card (which would have been a burn), and his exposed card is placed on top of the deck to be used as the next burn.

That's for holdem/omaha type games. Stud and draw games have different rules.